# UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only meanwhile the dontRollbackOn was already set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the `Controller-Service-Dao` pattern on my back-end service, it's like that:

1. Controller

```
@RestController
public class A {
    @Autowired
    B b;

    @GetMapping("/path")
    public ResponseEntity methodA() throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(b.methodB());
    }
}
```

2. Service layer 1

```
    @Service
    public class B {
        @Autowired
        E e;
        @Transactional(dontRollbackOn = {Exception.class})
        public Map methodB() throws Exception {
            return e.methodE();
        }
    }
```

2.a. Service layer II

```
    @Service
    public class E {
        @Autowired
        C c;
        @Transactional(dontRollbackOn = {Exception.class})
        public Map methodE() throws Exception {
            List<D> ds = c.inquiry();
            for (D d : ds) {
                  
                try { // process every d here }
                catch(Exception ex) {d.setStatus("FAIL!");}
                c.save(d);
            }
            return new HashMap(){{ put("deleted_rows", c.delete()); }};
        }
    }
```

3. Dao

```
    @Component
    public class C {
        public List<D> inquiry() {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            return session.createQuery("from D").list();
        };
        public void save(D d){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(d);
        };

        public int delete() {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from D where createdDate < :today")
                .setParameter("today", today).executeUpdate();
        }
    }
```

The above is the simpler version of my real code. But I wonder what should I do to prevent this error : org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

When I see the log, there's indeed an error caught in the `try-catch` block inside the method `E.methodE()`. I also saw that the hibernate log of succeeded deleting the rows. But the issue is it got rolled back at last just when committing. What should I do to repair this? Is there mistake in this transactional annotation usage?

Answer (score 0):

In JPA domain almost all runtime exceptions cause marking current transaction as rollback-only, please check for example [ExceptionConverterImpl#convert](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/ExceptionConverterImpl.java#L91). The reason for that is very obvious: if something goes wrong that means persistence context is not in sync with DB anymore (we performed changes in persistence context, but failed to persist them), and the most straightforward "compensation" there is to rollback transaction.

Spring's `Transactional#noRollbackFor` does not work "as expected" for the most exceptions raised in JPA domain, and the only option is to write a code in more accurate way.